# Continued fraction expansion of a rational function

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, continued-fractions

Maybe I'm missing something, but what would be a good way to calculate the continued fraction expansion of a rational function $Z(s) = N(s)/D(s)$?

The built-in function `ContinuedFraction` seems to deal only on numbers, not on rational functions.

Here is an example:

Say, you have $Z(s) = \frac{1+18 s+24 s^2}{6s + 24 s^2} = 1 + \frac{1}{2s + \frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4s}}}$.

```
(1 + 18 s + 24 s^2)/(6 s + 24 s^2)
```

The form on the right-hand side would be the continued fraction expansion of Z(s),
that I'm looking for - or alternatively, the list of the coefficients for the
different powers of $s$.

Comment: Please provide a sample problem.

Comment: I don't have the proper references here to give you much detail, but I can give you some search terms. What you are asking is very strongly related to Cauer Synthesis, or generally Network Synthesis. A good starting reference on this is the book Network Synthesis by Van Valkenberg.

Comment: The method I am most familiar with has the variable in the partial numerators, while your example has it in the partial denominators. I'll see what I can do...

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6757/continued-fraction-of-an-infinite-sum

Comment: That sample problem should be something one can cut and paste i.e. in Mathematica InputForm.

Answer (score 8):

As I noted in a comment, you could perform the [Thiele continued fraction expansion](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=elIyqgYk6RsC&pg=PA164) of a rational function, which is of a slightly different form from the one requested in the OP; this might nevertheless be useful in other contexts.

One method for generating this is [Viscovatov's algorithm](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=elIyqgYk6RsC&pg=PA16), which can be implemented in *Mathematica* like so:

```
viscovatov[cof_?VectorQ] := Module[{n = Length[cof] - 1, v},
   v = NestList[PadRight[{Last[#],
                          Table[Det[{d, #[[All, 1]]}],
                                {d, Transpose[Drop[#, None, 1]]}]}] &,
                {cof, UnitVector[n + 1, 1]}, n][[2 ;;, 1, 1]];
   Prepend[Rest[FoldList[1/(#1 #2) &, 1, Rest[v]]] Most[v], First[cof]]]
```

For instance, by using the asymptotic series coefficients (since the starting rational function is singular at $s=0$):

```
f = (1 + 18 s + 24 s^2)/(6 s + 24 s^2); n = 3;

rd = viscovatov[Table[SeriesCoefficient[f, {s, ∞, k}], {k, 0, n + 1}]]
   {1, 2, 3, 4}

First[rd] + ContinuedFractionK[1/s, Indexed[rd, k], {k, 2, n + 1}]
   1 + 1/((2 + 1/((3 + 1/(4 s)) s)) s)
```

where the last expression is equivalent to the one in the OP through an [equivalence transformation](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=zUUgs4BgcgoC&pg=PA77).

On the other hand, if you have a function that is finite at the origin:

```
f = (24 + 18 t + t^2)/(6 (4 + t)); n = 3;

rd = viscovatov[Table[SeriesCoefficient[f, {t, 0, k}], {k, 0, n + 1}]]
   {1, 2, 3, 4}

First[rd] + ContinuedFractionK[t, Indexed[rd, k], {k, 2, n + 1}]
   1 + t/(2 + t/(3 + t/4))
```

Comment: `viscovatov[{1, 1, 3, 7, 19, 47, 125, 315, 825}]` gives `{1, 1, -(1/3), -(9/2), -(1/6), ComplexInfinity, 0, ComplexInfinity}`, with some 1/0 errors along the way, what does this signify?

Comment: @მამუკა, yes, that's the sticky part of this implementation of Viscovatov. That means this should be treated the same as the result of `viscovatov[{1, 1, 3, 7, 19, 47}]`, even if `Series[(-1 + 2 t^2)/(-1 + t + 4 t^2), {t, 0, 8}]` only shows agreement up to the term in $t^5$.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
polyIter[{a_, b_, c_}, x_] := Module[{q, n},
    q = PolynomialQuotient[a, b, x];
    n = Exponent[q, x];
    {b, a - b #, #} &@If[n < 1, q, (Coefficient[q, x^n] x^n)] // Simplify
]

myPolyContinuedFraction[p_, q_, x_] := Last /@ Rest@ NestWhileList[polyIter[#, x] &, {p, q, 0}, Length@CoefficientList[#[[2]], x] > 0 &, 1]
```

`myPolyContinuedFraction` takes your polynomials and returns a continued fraction

```
 n[s_] := (1 + 18 s + 24 s^2);
 d[s_] := (6 s + 24 s^2);
 myPolyContinuedFraction[n[s], d[s], s]
```

in the form of a list of continued fraction coefficients

```
 {1, 2 s, 3, 4 s}
```

This can be put back into the usual form using the appropriate mathematica function

```
FromContinuedFraction[myPolyContinuedFraction[n[s], d[s], s]] == n[s]/d[s] // Simplify
```

which yields

```
True
```

as required.

Addendum: If instead you require something that takes `f[s_]:=n[s]/d[s]` as an argument simply use

```
 myPolyContinuedFraction2[f_, x_] := myPolyContinuedFraction[Numerator[f], Denominator[f], x]

 FromContinuedFraction[myPolyContinuedFraction2[n[s]/d[s], s]] == n[s]/d[s] // Simplify
```

which yields

```
True
```

Comment: Thank you! It works in each separate case. However what I would like to hold is that for a series like `f[x]+O[x]^n`, the *initial* terms of the continued fraction stabilize with $n$. In my case that I asked @J about, for example `1+x+3x^2+7x^3`, your list is `{7 t^3,0,3 t^2,0,t,1}` and for `1+x+3x^2` it is `{3 t^2,0,t,1}`, i. e. it is sort of backwards of what I would like to see.

Comment: The expansion you have asked for treats the highest exponent as the dominant term in the continued fraction expansion. It seems very unnatural to expect a similar expansion when you have changed the dominant term. Instead these continued fractions are stable when you remove the lowest powers of $x$, i.e.e truncate $1+x+3x^2+7x^3$ to $x+3x^2+7x^3$. A continued fraction expansion that stabilises in the manner you asked for can be obtained by rewriting your polynomials in terms of $y=1/x$, though the continued fraction coefficients will be powers of $y = 1/x$, not $x$.

Comment: `myPolyContinuedFraction2[1+1/x+3/x^2+7/x^3,x]` just returns `{(7+3 x+x^2+x^3)/x^3}`; as for `myPolyContinuedFraction2[Factor[1+x+3x^2+7x^3/.x->1/y],y]`, it gives `{1,y,-(1/3),-((9 y)/2),4/147,(7 y)/2}`, which is closer to what I want indeed. But, as you said, it is in terms of $1/x$, not $x$

Comment: The second case is what I had in mind. I cant really see a better solution. It is a feature of continued fractions that they have this kind of downstream sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

`f(x)=N(x)/D(x)` is rational function, where `N(x)=n[0]+n[1]*x+...+n[k]*(x^k)` is numerator and `D(x)=d[0]+d[1]*x+...+d[k]*(x^k)` is denominator of f(x).
`deg(N)=deg(D)=k`.

Continued fraction expansion of f(.):

`f(x)=a[0]+1/(b[1]*x+1/(a[1]+1/(b[2]*x+1/(a[2]+...+1/(b[k]*x+1/a[k])...)))), f(x)=<a[0], b[1]*x, a[1], b[2]*x, a[2],..., b[k]*x, a[k]>`

The list of the CFE-coefficients of f(x):

```
a[0] = n[k]/d[k];

For[i=1, i<=k, i++, {
  For[j=0, j<=k-i, j++, n[j]=n[j]-a[i-1]*d[j]],
  b[i]=d[k-i+1]/n[k-i],
  For[j=1, j<=k-i, j++, d[j]=d[j]-b[i]*n[j-1]],
  a[i]=n[k-i]/d[k-i]
}] 

Table[a[i], {i,0,k}]
Table[b[i], {i,1,k}]
```

Comment: What about the case of one of the n[i] or d[i] equal to zero?

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
CFExpand[rp_] := 
 Module[{g0, gf, rpoly = Together[rp], lff, lft, tog, var, 
   vars = Variables[rp], wx},
  CFEvaluate[expan_] := 
   If[Length[expan] != 2, Return[Null], 
    If[ListQ[expan[[2]][[2]]], 
     Return[expan[[1]] + expan[[2]][[1]]/CFEvaluate[expan[[2]][[2]]]],
      Return[expan[[1]] + expan[[2]][[1]]/expan[[2]][[2]]]]];
  LowFactor[poly_] := Module[{var2, vars2 = Variables[poly], w1, w2},
    If[vars2 != {}, var2 = vars2[[1]]; 
     w1 = CoefficientList[poly, var2]; 
     w2 = Map[{#, w1[[#]]} &, Range[Length[w1]]]; 
     var2^(Complement[w2, Select[w2, #[[2]] == 0 &]][[1]][[1]] - 1), 1]
    ];
  If[rp == Null, Return[Null], Nothing];
  If[Length[vars] == 0, Return[rpoly], var = vars[[1]]; 
   lff = LowFactor[Numerator[rpoly]]; gf = Together[rpoly/lff]; 
   g0 = gf /. var -> 0; wx = LowFactor[Numerator[gf]]; 
   tog = Together[gf - g0]; lft = LowFactor[Denominator[wx/tog]]; 
   Return[CFEvaluate[{lff*g0, {lff wx lft, 
       CFExpand[Together[(lft wx)/tog]]}}]]]]
```

Then

```
CFExpand[(x - x^3/6 + x^5/120 - x^7/5040)/(
 1 - x^2/2 + x^4/24 - x^6/720)]
=x + x^3/(
 3 + x^2/(-(5/6) + x^2/(
   252 + x^2/(-(4/75) + x^2/(-(22500/31) + (1050 x^2)/31)))))
```

Comment: Hope you find this useful.

Comment: A minor comment: Why not define CFEvaluate and LowFactor outside of the function CFExpand? It seems pointless to make these definitions every time you run CFExpand, and it also makes the code harder to read.

Comment: I agree, my intention was to make the function standalone and self contained. One can easily move the functions outside CFExpand without modification.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being so late to the party, I realize this is some five years old. I am not very active on m.se.

First I point out that "*the* continued fraction expansion", as you have called it, emphasis added by me, is not restricted to continued fractions of the form $K\frac 1{b_n}$, called the *simple* continued fractions. Usually this is what people refer to when they just say "continued fraction" without further context. And this is indeed how M's ContinuedFraction function operates. But in continued fraction literature the term refers to the general case $K\frac{a_n}{b_n}$, giving you much more flexibility.

As others on this page have already mentioned, Viskovatov is your friend. With Viskovatov you can directly develop the form you have already found or

$\cfrac{1}{6 z}+\cfrac{7 z}{3z+\cfrac{48 z^4}{7 z^2+12 z^3}}$

In M you could for example set this up as

```
c[0,0]=0;
c[0,1]=6z;
c[0,2]=24z^2;
c[1,0]=1;
c[1,1]=18z;
c[1,2]=24z^2;
c[i_?Negative,_]:=0;
c[m_,n_]:=c[m-1,0]c[m-2,n+1]-c[m-2,0]c[m-1,n+1];
Table[c[m, 0], {m, 0, 5}]
```

and take the last 5 five elements as partial numerators and the first five elements as partial denominators and simplify. You find a good description of the Viskovatov method in [1] on which the above recursion is based.

You can make continued fractions really powerful if you allow reciprocals in the partial numerators and partial denominators. Using your example this does not result in a "better" expression, it has fewer nesting levels but needs more complicated expressions, but you have asked a more general question and then given a specific example. You were after "a good way to calculate the continued fraction expansion of a rational function", and in that generality I suggest to not restricting your arsenal to only the simple continued fractions. In your specific example the simple continued fraction seems just fine, but that's a specific example on a more general question.

Viskovatov can be tricky if there is a 0 in the first column of the table that the algorithm is based on. There are ways to cope with that, as described in [2]. Another method is described in [3], but that too does not always work, because the required power series may have expressions of the type $\frac 1z$ as a series term, and it produces only continued fractions of the form $K \frac {a_nz}1$, which are called *regular C-fractions*, which are a special case of the *ordinary continued fractions*. They are the "opposite" of what you are using: all partial *denominators* are 1.

I am in the process of finalizing a book on continued fractions with M where you will be able to read about this in more detail.

[1] Cuyt et al., Handbook of Continued Fractions for Special Functions, Springer

[2] Khovanskii, The Application of Continued Fractions and their Generalizations to Problems in Approximation Theory, Nordhoff

[3] Lorentzen, Waadeland, Continued Fractions with Applications, North-Holland